# Reuse a series style in PGFplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have a lot of PGFplots in my document with a consistent style throughout, managed through a shared cycle list.

Now I'd like to re-use a previous plot style within the same PGFplot.

As an example, here I want to say that the third plot should use the same style as the first plot, but without specifying what that style is (since this will be given elsewhere in the cycle list).

[image]

(Sorry about the ugly cropping on the right of the image :P)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

%and define new styles like this:
% \pgfplotsset{
%    ...
%}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[ylabel=y,
    xlabel=x,]
        \addplot
        coordinates
        {
            (0,10)
            (10,0)
        };
        \addlegendentry{Descending}

        \addplot
        coordinates
        {
            (0,3)
            (10,5)
        }; 
        \addlegendentry{Ascending}

        \addplot
        coordinates
        {
            (0,7)
            (10,5)
        };
        % Reuse descending style
    \end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd like the third brown plot to have the same style as the first blue plot, but without manually specifying the style details like `blue`, `mark=o`, etc. Can this be done directly?

Optionally, if that's not possible, can I load the first style in the active cycle list for the third plot?

Comment: I found the answer while writing up the question. :) But interested to hear if it's possible to "label" the style of a particular plot and recall it later in the same graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pgfplots` comes with a `\label` / `\ref` mechanism to label plots and to reference their style somewhere else. While this mechanism is intended to generate legends somewhere inside of the text, one can also access the style options of the labelled plot using the key `refstyle`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

%and define new styles like this:
% \pgfplotsset{
%    ...
%}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[ylabel=y,
    xlabel=x,]
        \addplot
        coordinates
        {
            (0,10)
            (10,0)
        };
        \addlegendentry{Descending}
        \label{plot:1}

        \addplot
        coordinates
        {
            (0,3)
            (10,5)
        }; 
        \addlegendentry{Ascending}

        \addplot[refstyle={plot:1}]
        coordinates
        {
            (0,7)
            (10,5)
        };
        % Reuse descending style
    \end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this requires two compiles over the document. Details of this `\label` / `\ref` mechanism can be found in section "Legends with label and ref" in the manual.

Comment: Much more convenient than my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Optionally, if that's not possible, can I load the first style in the active cycle list for the third plot?

You can use

```
\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-2}
```

to shift the cycle list counter backwards or forwards, where we can achieve what we need by adding the above command before the third plot.

Note that this does not accumulate ... hence if you wanted the fourth plot to be ascending, you would need to add:

```
\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-2}
```

again.